# What is the integral of $e^x \tan(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

What is the integral of $e^x \tan(x)$? Using basic theorems it is difficult to get I think.

Comment: Nothing elementary, I'm afraid. You'll need the Gaussian hypergeometric function for this...

Comment: Please explain meaning of 'Nothing elementary'? Please provide me details regarding elementary and non elementary.

Comment: You are aware of the concept of an "elementary function", no? The integral you have cannot be expressed in terms of those.

Comment: Sorry, Still I am not getting what is an 'Elementary Function'. Could you please explain it to me or provide some links to some websites?

Comment: I wonder if someone could provide a proof of the fact stated here, using differential galois theory.

Comment: Elementary Functions are the basic functions that we all know and all of the functions that we can make out of them, for example: $x$,$\sin x$, $e^x$, $\arctan (\ln x)$ and so.. J.M meant that the answer for this integral will not be any combination of these functions.

Comment: "till I am not getting what is an 'Elementary Function'" - the result is not expressible in terms of algebraic functions, exponentials, logarithms, trigonometric functions and their inverses, and combinations/compositions thereof. Clear?

Comment: @sree: Concerning the concept of "elementary function" see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) Wikipedia's entry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\tan(x) = -i \frac{1-e^{-2ix}}{1+e^{-2ix}} = -i - 2 i \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k e^{-2ikx}$$ 
(converging for $\text{Im}(x) < 0$)

$$\begin{align}
\int e^x \tan(x)\ dx &= -i e^x - 2 i \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \int e^{(1-2ik)x}\ dx \\
&= -i e^x -2i \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{1-2ik} e^{(1-2ik)x} + C \\
&= -i{{ e}^{x}}-{\rm LerchPhi} \left( -{{ e}^{-2ix}},1,1+i/2
 \right) {{ e}^{(1-2i)x}} + C
\end{align}$$

This Lerch Phi function can also be expressed in terms of a hypergeometric function:

$${\rm LerchPhi} \left( z,1,1+\frac{i}{2} \right) = \frac{ 4-2i
 }{5} \ {\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}\left(1,1+\frac{i}{2};2+\frac{i}{2};z\right)}$$

Comment: I took the liberty of reformatting your maths, as it was line breaking in an odd place in my browser. I hope that's OK.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure sree was asking for an elementary answer, though it is possible.  I can't comment yet, so I'm putting this in an answer area, though it doesn't answer; my apologies.

Comment: Are there good (and accessible) references for sree for how to utilize hypergeometric functions for doing indefinite integrals?  For instance, would writing $e^x \tan(x)$ as a power series (or just the $\tan(x)$ part) and using some kind of uniform convergence and definitions of HG functions help?

Comment: Well, one possible route is to expand the integrand as a series, integrate termwise, and then apply any number of methods for recognizing hypergeometric series, like the ones embodied in the work of Gosper, Zeilberger, Koutschan, etc.

Comment: Fair enough, though I think that "any number of methods" probably requires some elaboration.  @Robert's answer is great - is there a _specific_ book which would introduce to these sorts of things by hand (as opposed to using an algorithm)?  (Even if one has to pore through a massive table of such series...)

Answer (score 2):

It is not expressible as an elementary function.  integrals.com expresses it using hypergeometric functions:

$$-i \left( -{{\rm e}^{x}}
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,-i/2;1-i/2;\,-{{\rm e}^{2ix}})}+ \left( 
1/5-2i/5 \right) {{\rm e}^{ \left( 1+2i \right) x}}
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,1-i/2;2-i/2;\,-{{\rm e}^{2ix}})}
 \right)$$

Comment: I couldn't find any method to solve this. :(